# JSON api responses have strange behavior in browser

Tags: javascript, c, http, arduino, esp8266

I'm creating an API on a wifi microcontroller. The website make requests and the microcontroller (ESP8266) should respond JSON data.

I have stranges problems with HTTP responses:

- When the website does the first request, it receive a blank response

  - After that, responses work but: when I change the request parameters the website get the response from the previous one

the ESP8266 sends homepage with no issue with this HTTP response:
    `client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");`
    `client.println("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");`
    `client.println("");`
    `client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");`

The problem happen with this code:

```
// read incoming request

String request = client.readStringUntil('\r\n');

client.flush();


// read the request

if (request.length() > 15) {

// check if request is an api call and not a favicon call

if (request.indexOf("favicon") < 0) {

rqlength = request.length() - 15 ;

request = request.substring(5);

rqs = "";

rq["title"] = "request";

rq["date"] = request.substring(0,8);

rq["hour"] = String(timeClient.getHours());

serializeJson(rq, rqs);

// check if request is an api call and not a favicon request

// send the request to arduino

Serial.print(rqs);

// wait the response from the arduino

while (Serial.available()) {

incdata = Serial.readString();

cansend = true;

}

// send the arduino JSON data to the client : The issue seems to come from here ?

client.println(F("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"));

client.println(F("Content-Type: application/json"));

client.println(F("Connection: close"));

client.println("");

client.print(incdata);

}
```

The problem seems to happen because of cache or http header ?
But I can't find the solution.
Any idea ?

Comment: if you are trying to send json than your "Content-Type" needs to be "application/json" not text/html.

Comment: The first 4 lines of code show working code (that send my html page). The code that sends JSON is at the end of my post. Sorry if that was not clear. The content-type is application/json in this code